# Exceptions - Best Practices

Tags: c#, exception

I have been thinking generally about exception handling.

What would be the best practice for implementing a method that gets a `User` object based on the supplied username parameter. See below.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">Username</param>
    /// <returns>User instance</returns>
    public Model.User GetUser(string username)
    {
        return Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username.ToLower() == username.ToLower());
    }
```

if no user exists with that `username` parameter, would it be better to return a null `User` object or rather throw a custom exception specifying that the user does not exist.

Comment: What are you expecting from calling the method? Does it matter if a user is returned or is it mandatory?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling?sort=votes

Comment: IMHO exceptions exist for exceptional cases, if a user does not exist yo should handle it returning null. on the other hand if you have a db connection problem you should handle the exception, rethrow it, etc...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw an exception. Otherwise, your caller, and your caller's caller, and everyone else will need to check for `null`, or will need to handle an empty collection.

If this is a general-purpose method, meant to be used in a context where the caller *knows* he needs to check for null, then I'd do this a bit differently. I would have a `private` method that returns null if there are no users who match. I would add a caller which uses the "try" pattern:

```
public bool TryGetUser(string username, out Model.User user)
```

and also one that simply returns the user, but throws an exception if not found

```
public Model.User GetUser(string username)
```

Comment: This post best answers my concerns, and in addition, I have read somewhere that if a module cannot for whatever reason do what it says it can do which in this case is to return a `User` object then throw an exception.

Comment: They won't have to check for null if you implement null object pattern.

Comment: I disagree completely with this answer. Exceptions are for exceptional situations. Failing to find a matching entry is *not* an exceptional situation. Returning `null` makes both perfect logical and perfect programming sense- you found nothing, therefore return nothing. In fact, code like the above answer suggests results in developers using try/catch as part of the control flow of their code, which is terrible practice.

Comment: It depends on the contract of the method. If the contract is "get a user", then an exception should be thrown when  you can't get a user. If the contract is "get a user or null if you can't find one", then return null. But if the contract (implicit or otherwise) causes the caller to expect a user to be returned, then you need to throw an exception when no user is returned.

Comment: In what circumstance is it beneficial that the method throws if it doesn't match? It can result in 3 scenarios: a) The programmer has to *check themselves* if the collection contains the value beforehand to prevent the exception, thereby obviating the need for the method in the first place. b) The programmer wraps the call in try/catch and uses that to determine success/failure- terrible programming practice. c) Crashes the program with an unhelpful exception message. By returning `null` the **caller** not the **callee** decides what they should do. I agree that is needs to be documented.

Comment: @MgSam: If I call a method that says, "I promise to return the user with this user id", then I want it to throw when it breaks its promise. That way, I can write code that depends on the promise being met (i.e., it doesn't have to check for null).

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be if the program cannot continue without a user then throw an exception. If it is ok that you cannot find a user or that this would be a log-in fail then I would return null. I would only throw an exception if the program could not continue without getting the user and it could not say redirect to log-on again.

Remember throwing an exception is more of an expensive operation that returning null too (I mean nothing noticeable and do think like this (micro-optimization) but exceptions should be used for normal business logic)

Comment: forget about being expensive, make sure the program does what it needs to do properly.,

Comment: right the thing is this method is intended to be used in various scenarios, `login` and to get `User` from just knowing the username.
Or would it be better to have separate methods for login and getting a user ?

Comment: @DarthVader yes agreed, I just wanted to add that there is a cost to exceptions

Comment: @kooldave98 Wouldn't you want to kept the logged in user in a session object already after they are logged in?

Comment: @BradSemrad this module is not only intended for Logging-In, it is a general method to get a user, and can be leveraged for other purposes as the developer sees fit.

Comment: @kooldave98 Ok then I still would recommend returning null and let the callers choose to throw an exception or not

Comment: @BradSemrad: in reality, what happens is that the callers "decide" to throw a `NullReferenceException` - and the developer trying to fix the problem may have trouble figuring out where the `null` came from. Better to throw an exception at the point of the failure.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Isn't that what method level documentation is for?

Comment: @BradSemrad: if you mean that method level documentation is created in order to be ignored, then yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

First I just want to suggest an improvement on your method of comparing strings without case sensitivity.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a user.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="username">Username</param>
/// <returns>User instance</returns>
public Model.User GetUser(string username)
{
    return Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => 
       string.Compare(u.Username, username, true));
}
```

[String.Compare on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

**Now my suggestion on this issue**

Rather than return null. You may like to return a Null object, using the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

```
public class User
{

  public static readonly User Null = new Null{Username = "Anonymous"};

  ...

}
```

Then your method becomes:

```
public Model.User GetUser(string username)
{
    return Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => 
       string.Compare(u.Username, username, true)) ?? Model.User.Null;
}
```

This is useful in situations where `null` is undesirable. It removes the need to check for `null` later. If this user object has rights associated for example, you can just make sure the "null user" has no rights.

Comment: Of course, this makes no sense if the `User` object is meant to be something real in the system. Now you have to make sure, not only that the null user has no rights, but that they can't be listed in a list of users, or in fact, that the null user actually acts like it doesn't exist. You'd do better with an exception.

Comment: @JohnSaunders In this case I agree. The method is called `GetUser`. it would not be smart to then return a `User` that was not the user requested. But if the name I chose was better, you might not mind it showing up in a list of users. e.g. "Anonymous"

Comment: Perhaps a "User" is a bad example for the Null Object pattern, but I can't think of any cases where I'd prefer to return a fake entity than to admit that the requested entity does not exist. Fake entities don't usually exist in the problem domain, in my experience.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes I admit that returning it from this function given it's name is probably not a good use if it. However, I think this could be useful as a default state before a user has logged in for example, to save lots of null checks. Depends on what the rest of the code looks like really.

Comment: Again, not a great example. In ASP.NET, for instance, if my code needed to know if the current user were Authenticated, I would simply check `User.IsAuthenticated`. More likely, I'd simply specify in the .config file that most pages require authentication, then I wouldn't have to check at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the calling method can decide whether or not the result of no user being found requires the throwing of an exception.  If a username is provided, but not found, returning null makes sense to me and letting the calling code decide how it needs to proceed.

Given how generic the method is, why would you throw an exception if a supplied username is not found?  It's one thing if a database error occurs etc, but if the SELECT results in no rows, I think it is not exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the previously posted answers.

Exceptions should be used only in *exceptional* circumstances. Failing to find a matching value is not exceptional. IMO, returning `null` is much more elegant- it leaves the decision about whether to throw an exception to the caller, not the callee, and it makes sense; you ask the method for a user and if there is none it returns nothing.

In addition, your code and the other answers iterate through the entire collection each time, which is going to be unnecessarily slow. You should use a dictionary for quick lookups, (unless, of course, there are frequent changes to the Users collection which makes caching impossible).

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<String,User> _userLookup;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _userLookup = Context.Users.ToDictionary(u => u.UserName.ToLower());
    }

    private User getUserByName(String name)
    {
        var lowerName = name.ToLower();
        return _userLookup.ContainsKey(lowerName) ? _userLookup[lowerName] : null;
    }     
}
```